# two set of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Can you please check my calculation below.

Thanks

Comment: can you latex this?

Answer (score 0):

Differential equations like this are easy to check - take appropriate derivatives of your answer and see if they satisfy the original equation for all times $t$.  We see $X_1'(t)=X_2(0)$ but it's supposed to equal $X_2(t)$.  Going from your second set of equations to the third you did an invalid "integration".  I would say you should check your notes/book if this is for a class for the particular techniques you ought to use.